# Convert time format from 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' to 'MM-dd-yyyy' in hive

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hiveql

How to convert time format from  `06/23/2020 07:57:45` to `06-23-2020` in hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `split` and concatenation:

```
with your_data as (
select  '06/23/2020 07:57:45' as str
)

select concat_ws('-',splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2]) as Result
from
(
select split(str,'[/ ]') as splitted
  from your_data
)s
```

Result:

```
06-23-2020
```

Using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(string, format_from), format_to)`:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(str,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'MM-dd-yyyy') as Result
  from your_data
```

Result:

```
06-23-2020
```